# How to replace a specific character after the occurrence of a string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a specific requirement-
I need to replace all '@' symbols after a '~' is encountered in a string using regular expression in python.

**Sample inputs**-

```
a) //div[@id='1234'] ~ div[@id='abcd'] ~ a[@href='/xyz']

b) //div[@id='1234']/div[@id='abcd'] ~ a[@href='/xyz']
```

**Desired output**-

```
a) //div[@id='1234'] ~ div[id='abcd'] ~ a[href='/xyz']

b) //div[@id='1234']/div[@id='abcd'] ~ a[@href='/xyz']
```

Note- The position of the '~' symbol can appear anywhere and we need to replace only after it has been encountered.

I have tried to create a few regex but not been successfull so far.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex pattern with two capture groups:

```
r"(~[^@]*)(@)"   # first capture group starts with ~ and excludes @
                 # 2nd capture group just has @
```

Substitution keeps first capture group in string s

```
re.sub(r"(~[^@]*)(@)", r"\1", s)
```

Example:

```
print(re.sub(r"(~[^@]*)(@)", r"\1", r"//div[@id='1234'] ~ div[@id='abcd'] ~ a[@href='/xyz']")
# Output: "//div[@id='1234'] ~ div[id='abcd'] ~ a[href='/xyz']"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regexes too - find the index of `~` in your string and replace `@` characters after that index

```py
s = "//div[@id='1234'] ~ div[@id='abcd'] ~ a[@href='/xyz']"
out_s = s[:s.index('~')] + s[s.index('~'):].replace('@', '')
```

**Output**

```
"//div[@id='1234'] ~ div[id='abcd'] ~ a[href='/xyz']"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The approach is also working